# 'MainActivity()' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Intent)'

Tags: java, android, android-intent, constructor

How can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView iconImage;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private Button register;
    private Button login;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iconImage = findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);

        linearLayout.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1);

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-1000);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(false);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new myAnimationListener());

         iconImage.setAnimation(animation);

         register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 new MainActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));  **Here saying that is create constructor**
             }
         });

         login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 new MainActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));**Here saying that is create constructor**
             }
         });
    }
    private class myAnimationListener implements Animation.AnimationListener{
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             iconImage.clearAnimation();
             iconImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             linearLayout.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    }
}
```

If I do not use new operator before `MainActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));`  it shows error is that Method call expected. How can this error be resolved?

Comment: prolly, you need to use method which starts intent... not operator new with contrcutor which doesn't even exists

Comment: what do you want to do? if you want to start login or register activity why simply don't start them instead of passing new intent in a new Main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```java
new MainActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

with:

```java
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

(and similarly for the second `new MainActivity()` line)

Note that the use of `startActivity()` is covered in most books and introductory courses on Android app development. FWIW, [here is a free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), and [here is the chapter in that book talking about multiple activities and `startActivity()`](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-activities-001.html).